# Xcode UILabel bug? Line spacing cropping text with a UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, interface-builder

I have some designs I'm following for an iOS project.  The font used is Avenir with relatively tight line spacing.

Some of these labels will have dynamic text, so I can't just make the label's size larger since the size should be determined by the content.

By default line spacing for a UILabel ends up pretty large.

[image: Default Line Spacing]

If I adjust the `Line Height Multiple` or the `Max Height`, the text along the top ends up cropped.
[image: Height Multiple]

---

[image]

It should behave like this (Affinity Designer)...
[image]

Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. By adding

> minimumLineHeight

```
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: venue.name)
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineHeightMultiple = 0.68
style.minimumLineHeight = nameLabel.font.lineHeight
string.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle,
                    value: style,
                    range: NSMakeRange(0, venue.name.count))
nameLabel.attributedText = string
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the UILabel has several quirks when it comes to vertical adjustments. A somewhat hacky solution is to move the baseline of the first line down as needed. Depending on if your string ends with a newline, and the amount of tightening you do, you might need to add one or two extra newlines also, otherwise the rendering engine will clip the last line.

The code snippet assumes that `self.label` already has an attributed string assigned to it, and that it has line separator character `0x2028` between the lines. This is usually true when entering multi-line text in IB.

```
// 0x2028 is the unicode line separator character
// Use \n instead if it is what you have
// or calculate the length of the first line in some other way
NSInteger lengthOfFirstLine = [self.label.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2028"][0].length;
NSMutableAttributedString *s = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.label.attributedText];

// Add two more blank lines so that the rendering engine doesn't clip the last line
[s appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]];

// Move the baseline offset for the first line down
// the other lines will adjust to this
// 50 is a value you will have to find what looks best for you
[s addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(-50) range:NSMakeRange(0, lengthOfFirstLine)];
self.label.attributedText = s;
```